# save get'd variable (after assign)

Tags: r

Why can't R find this variable?

```
assign(paste0('my', '_var'), 2)
get(paste0('my', '_var')) ## isn't this returning an object?
save(get(paste0('my', '_var')), file =  paste0('my', '_var.RDATA'))
```

This throws the error:

```
Error in save(paste0("my", "_var"), file = paste0("my", "_var.RDATA")) : 
  object ‘paste0("my", "_var")’ not found
```

Comment: `get(...)` returns a *value*, not a *reference* to a value. From [`?get`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.3/topics/get), sub-titled *"Return the Value of a Named Object"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the help page, the `save()` function expects "the names of the objects to be saved (as symbols or character strings)." Those values are not evaulated, ie you can't put in functions that will eventually return strings or raw values themselves. Use the `list=` parameter if you want to call a function to return a string the the name of a variable.

```
save(list=paste0('my', '_var'), file =  paste0('my', '_var.RDATA'))
```

Though using get/assign is often not a good practice in R. They are usually better ways so you might want to rethink your general approach.

And finally, if you are saving a single object, you might want to consider `saveRDS()` instead. Often that's the behavior people are expecting when they use the `save()` function.

Comment: +1 for *"not a good practice in R"*. (This isn't a pedagogic discussion trying to convert analysts into CS professionals ... it's a suggestion for how to stay out of trouble by using "risky programming practices". Strong suggestion.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I generally avoid it but can't think of another approach to save dynamically made `.RDATA` files.

Comment: So you really need `rdata` files? Otherwise, as I mentioned, `rds` files would probably be much easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `save` says that `...` should be

> the names of the objects to be saved (as symbols or character strings).

And indeed if you type `save` into the console you can see that the source has the line

```
names <- as.character(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
```

where `substitute` captures its argument and doesn't evaluate it. So as the error suggests, it is looking for an object with the name `paste0('my', '_var')`, not evaluating the expressions supplied.